# extract number from a string 

Tags: bash

i have the following string

```
Device Enabled (126):   1
```

can i extract in a variable VAR only 126 and NOT (126) ?

p.s 126 = random number

please help me !

EDIT 
i paste my script so u can understand the solution

```
ID=`xinput list | grep -i TouchPad | awk -F= '{ print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
VALOREENABLE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Enabled |awk '{print $3}'`
VALORESENSE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Profile |awk '{print $3}'
```

in my case VALOREENABLE = (126)
and VALORESENSE (256)  i want 126, 256 only without () :(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it. Here's the one that first comes to mind for me:

```
VALOREENABLE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Enabled | grep -o "(.*)" | tr -d '()'`
VALORESENSE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Profile | grep -o "(.*)" | tr -d '()'`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Device Enabled (126):   1" | grep -P -o "[0-9]+" | head -1
```

- **echo** puts your string into the pipe
- that goes to **grep**, which is a program to apply regular expressions. The option `-P` enables PEARL like behaviour (which enables you to use the `+`), and the `-o` tells grep to only output the matching part of the string. Each match will be printed to a new line
- use **head** to pick the line you want. Since we want the first number, we will pick the first line. If you were interested in the one, you would do `head -2`.

Comment: sho my edit post :P

Answer (score 2):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/' <<<"Device Enabled (126):   1"
```

Result:

```
126
```

so for your script you could try:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=`xinput list | grep -i TouchPad | awk -F= '{ print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
VALOREENABLE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Enabled |awk '{print $3}'`
#VALORESENSE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Profile |awk '{print $3}'`
VALORESENSE=`xinput list-props $ID | grep -i Profile | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/' `
echo $VALORESENSE
```

Comment: show my edit post

Answer (score 2):

OK, I will toss in my 2c, you can do it directly with awk

```
ID=`xinput list | grep -i TouchPad | awk -F= '{ print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
VALOREENABLE=`xinput list-props $ID | awk '/Enabled/ {print substr ($3, 2, 3) }'`
VALORESENSE=`xinput list-props $ID | awk '/Profile/ {print substr ($3, 2, 3) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell can do it:

```
str="Device Enabled (126):   1"
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS="()"
words=($str)
number=${words[1]}
```

Or, if you really like using awk, set the field separator to be either parenthesis

```
number=$(awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' <<< "Device Enabled (126):   1")
```

Using your example code, I'd write:

```
ID=$(xinput list | awk -F= '/TouchPad/ {split($2, a, /[[:space:]]\+/); print a[1]}')
PROPS=$(xinput list-props $ID)
VALOREENABLE=$(awk -F '[()]' '/Enabled/ '{print $2}' <<< "$PROPS")
VALORESENSE=$(awk -F '[()]' '/Profile/ '{print $2}' <<< "$PROPS")
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the ID could be simplified as so (note the use of `$()` instead of backticks):

```
ID=$(xinput list | awk '/TouchPad/{sub(/^.*id=/,"");sub(/\[.*/,"");print}')
```

Personally, I'd use `perl` in extracting the numbers:

```
VALOREENABLE=$(xinput list-props $ID | perl -ne 's/.*\((.*)\).*/$1/ and print if /Enabled/' )
VALORESENSE=$(xinput list-props $ID | perl -ne 's/.*\((.*)\).*/$1/ and print if /Profile/' )
```